# Duplicated content with json:api related links

Tags: api, duplicates, json-api

In the [Resource Linkage section](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage) of json:api specification I found that you can fetch a related resource object with a url like this, `http://example.com/articles/1/author`, making reference to "the author of the article with id 1".

In the site complete example we can see that the author has id 9.

```json
// ...
{
  "type": "articles",
  "id": "1",
  "attributes": {
    "title": "Rails is Omakase"
  },
  "relationships": {
    "author": {
      "links": {
        "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/author",
        "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/author"
      },
      "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
    }
  },
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/articles/1"
  }
}
// ...
```

So, if I understood it, I would be able to request the same resource with two different urls:

```
http://example.com/articles/1/author
http://example.com/authors/9
```

Is this ok?
Wouldn't this be considerated [duplicate content](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The article you have linked](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content) talks about duplicated content in the context of a website. JSON:API specification is about an API. A website is typically meant to be read and consumed by humans. An API is meant for programs to be consumed. The SEO concerns raised by that article are not applyable to an API cause search engines like Google does not care about API responses. They may care about the website build based on the data fetch of that API. That website should have a unique URL or a `rel="canonical"` attribute.

Comment: Ok, I understood this has nothing to do with SEO and websites duplicated content, but then, would it be ok to have those two urls for the exactly same resource? Or is there any API rule that encourages us to avoid this practice?

Comment: The specification recommends having both URLs. Some might argue that this is not a fully RESTful design but I would more focus on the problem that it provides a solution for: The client doesn't have to know the IDs of the related resource to fetch them. Therefore the API might not need to load that IDs from the database in the first place but include a relationship link instead. This could be a huge performance improvement.